# Sub state bindings in ui-router/sample-app-angularjs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-ui-router

I'm studying the [sample app of UI-Router](https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angularjs) and got the question.

In *sample-app-angularjs/app/contacts/editContact.component.js* line71~74 it has:

```
export const editContact =  {
  bindings: { pristineContact: '<' },

  controller: EditContactController,
```

In *sample-app-angularjs/app/contacts/contacts.states.js* line29~38 it has:

```
export const viewContactState = {
  name: 'contacts.contact',
  url: '/:contactId',
  resolve: {
    // Resolve the contact, based on the contactId parameter value.
    // The resolved contact is provided to the contactComponent's contact binding
    contact: ['Contacts', '$transition$', (Contacts, $transition$) => Contacts.get($transition$.params().contactId)]
  },
  component: 'contactView'
};
```

And In *sample-app-angularjs/app/contacts/contacts.states.js* line49~61 it has:

```
export const editContactState = {
  name: 'contacts.contact.edit',
  url: '/edit',
  views: {
    // Relatively target the grand-parent-state's $default (unnamed) ui-view
    // This could also have been written using ui-view@state addressing: $default@contacts
    // Or, this could also have been written using absolute ui-view addressing: !$default.$default.$default
    '^.^.$default': {
      bindings: { pristineContact: "contact" },
      component: 'editContact'
    }
  }
};
```

My questions are on the parameter *pristineContact*:

1. How it is been passed from state *contacts.contact* to *contacts.contact.edit* and then to component *editContact*? I understand the  resolve *contact* in state *contacts.contact* is directly available in it's child state *contacts.contact.edit*, but I cannot find any knowledge-base document related to the clause 'bindings: { pristineContact: "contact" }' (line57) of *contacts.states.js*. I GUESS it passes the resolve down to it's component(s) so it's component(s) can use "bindings{...}" to input it.
2. I did not see in the template of component *editContact* it is used/referenced, but *$ctrl.contact* is used/referenced instead. -- I cannot understand why the name "pristineContact" is there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample app, the `editContact` component uses dirty checking to determine if a contact has been edited or not.  Dirty checking is used to prompt the user if they want to discard their changes if they switch to a different URL.

[image: confirm dialog]

### 1) How does it pass `contact` resolve?

As you stated, the `contact` resolve is available in the nested state.  However, the `editContact` component doesn't have a `contact` binding.  Instead, it has a `pristineComponent` binding.

In order to map the `contact` resolve to the `pristineContact` component binding, a `bindings` mapping is added to the state.

```
      bindings: { pristineContact: "contact" },
```

This supplies `pristineContact` component binding with the data from the `contact` resolve.

This guide describes resolve bindings: 
https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#resolve-bindings

... and this API doc has even more of the gory details: 
https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1viewdeclaration.html#bindings

### 2) What is `$ctrl.contact` and where is `pristineContact` in the template?

The `editContact` component's dirty checking creates a copy of the original (pristine) contact in `$onInit()`.  Any changes in the form are applied to the copy (`$ctrl.contact`):

```
  $onInit() {
    // Make an editable copy of the pristineContact
    this.contact = angular.copy(this.pristineContact);
  }
```

When the user clicks save, the *editable copy* is saved and then the parent state is activated, with `reload: true` to reload the changed data.

```
  /** Save the contact, then go to the grandparent state ('contacts') */
  save(contact) {
    this.Contacts.save(contact)
        .then(() => this.canExit = true)
        .then(() => this.$state.go("^", null, { reload: true }));
  }
```

The `pristineContact` is only used to make the initial copy and then to perform the dirty checking:

```
  uiCanExit() {
    if (this.canExit || angular.equals(this.contact, this.pristineContact)) {
      return true;
    }

    let message = 'You have unsaved changes to this contact.';
    let question = 'Navigate away and lose changes?';
    return this.DialogService.confirm(message, question);
  }
```